# Filter only email addresses in MondoDB compass and export

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

In MongoDB compass I want to filter all the records and get only email addresses so that I can export it. Kindly let me know what should I use in filter?

Comment: See [Compass - Query Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/query/filter/). Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For exporting from Compass see the documentation: [Export data from collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/import-export/#export-data-from-a-collection).